# Why doesn't the Exception class populate the __dict__ attribute?

Tags: python

Why doesn't the `Exception` (and derivatives) class populate instance attributes onto the `__dict__` special attribute like other classes?

For instance, a class derived from the `object` class stores instance attributes on the `__dict__` attribute:

```
class TestClass(object):
def __init__(self, *args):
    self.args = args

test = TestClass(1,2,3)
print(test.__dict__)
print(test.args)

>>>> {'args': (1, 2, 3)}
>>>> (1, 2, 3)
```

But, the `Exception` class has a different behavior:

```
test_exception = Exception(1,2,3)
print(test_exception.__dict__)
print(test_exception.args) 

>>>> {}
>>>> (1, 2, 3)
```

I expect to be able to see all the object's properties in the `__dict__` special attribute so I'm confused by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.7, at least:

```
>>> type(Exception.args)
<type 'getset_descriptor'>
```

`args` is not an instance variable; it's a descriptor, meaning it is a function that is invoked when you try to access `Exception().args`.

Comment: That makes sense, but where are the function arguments stored internally until returned via the `args` descriptor?

Comment: In CPython, at least, they are stored in the C data structure that implements an exception, and are not directly accessible via Python.